# Why there is a high inrush current when the microcontroller start-up(CC430f5137 from TI)?

Tags: microcontroller, inrush-current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwqwTW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: diagram]In my application, I need to measure the current consumption of the mcu (cc430f5137). To measure the current of the mcu. I insert a 10ohm resistor at the Vcc. Then, I connect the power supply to the Vcc and  observe the voltage across the resistor so that I =V/10.  I found that the current at start-up is around  80mA@1.8V  and 200mA @3.3V. It will last for a while and decrease gradually. Below is the picture of the waveform under 1.8V and the diagram of the board. The division of the waveform is **2 ms/div**.
[image: waveform of the voltage across the resistor @ 1.8V power supply]

What may cause such a high current at start-up? Is this normal and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

10 Ohms is way too big for a current sense resistor and is slowing the charging of the decoupling caps. Try 10 milliOhms.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any relationship between the charging speed and the start-up current?  Actually, I am using an ordinary resistor.

Comment: @Enob Those caps have to charge up. Is that really a problem?

Comment: thanks. So you mean the high current is caused by the charging of the capacitors?

Comment: @Enob That is the only thing I see.

Comment: @Enob if your schematic is true then 10 Ohm with 40 µF --> \$\tau \approx 0.4 ms\$ so it needs 2 ms to charge the caps, which is in the order of what you are measuring (there is a current draw, so it'll take longer than by the pure RC calculation).

Comment: Thank you @Arsenal. Could you tell me how to understand this by equations? Or tell me some keywords so that I can google them. Many thanks

Comment: @Enob it's the RC charge curve. [This seems a place to start](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html).

Comment: @Arsenal Thank you. I had understood the principle now.

Answer (score 1):

At a first estimate, you're trying to push 90uC into 50uF worth of caps at 1.8V.  Your inrush above, using a triangular approximation, shows about 104uC in the first 4ms or so.  Most of it will be the caps.  (The total charge delivered is the area under your scope trace.)

If you reduce your sense resistor, you will likely see a higher peak and a shorter tail, as the capacitors will charge faster.

Comment: Thank you very much. Should I include this inrush current into the calculation of the power consumption of the MCU since?  Previously, I think this high current is caused by the start-up of the MCU so that I include it into the calculation. Since it will finally be consumed by the MCU.

Comment: I wouldn't include it as part of the MCU power consumption.  You could get a fair estimate of the startup of the MCU itself by applying power and holding the MCU in reset.  Once the caps are charged, release reset and profile the current.  BTW, that chip has a lot of Vcc pins for that single lonely analog ground.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good idea. In my application, the mcu is supplied by an energy harvesting circuit, the circuit will open the Vcc for a short period once the harvested energy reach threshold. Therefore, the power supply at Vcc will be periodically  on/off. The power consumption I want to calculate is the  the energy needed for one period. So, I think inrush current should be included in my application. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to find an overall budget and you've removed Vcc between activations.  You might also want to consider reducing the capacitance across your supplies.  40uF on Vcc and 10uF on Vcore seems excessive for this design, and if your duty cycle is pretty low, charging the caps might account for the majority of your power use.  A single 10uF and a few 0.1uF ceramic caps near the uC's power pins would do more for padding than all that bulk capacitance.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried it already. I remove the capacitors, which improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

> What may cause such a high current at start-up? Is this normal and how to solve this problem?

You are charging up about 40 uF.
Initially, capacitors can be considered as a short circuit.
Only the ESR of the capacitors and the impedance of the voltage source and the impedance of the wiring limit this initial charging current.
The high current will exist longer the more capacitance has to be charged.

However, since you are measuring with 10 Ω this resistance limits the current significantly (considered to the other impedances).
The real inrush current will be quite higher.

> how to solve this problem?

- You could limit the inrush current by a resistance, but this might give you an undesired voltage drop in normal operation.
- You could also limit the inrush current with an inductor (because current through it cannot change instantly) but if not damped well enough, it may give undesired oscillations.
- You could also reduce the capacitance. Is 40 uF really needed? (Assuming the 10 uF are equal, this only reduces the duration, not the height of the inrush)

Comment: The total ESR of those capacitors (which appear to be ceramics) is going to be of the order of 5 - 10 m\$\Omega\$ so the initial inrush without any limiting will be rather large.

Comment: Thank you very much. This board is not designed by myself, I just bought it from the market.  The recommended capacitors at the Vcc are 10uF+10nF according to the datasheet.

Comment: If I limit the inrush current, will the power consumption go down?

Comment: Is 10R from Cap to IC or to Cap?

Comment: @ Tony  Please see my updated picture.

Comment: @PeterSmith ESR will indeed be in that order, but wiring+connectors more likely in the order of several tens to hundreds of mΩ.